# RxJava2, 2 subscribers for an Observable/Flowable but onNext getting called on any one

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, watchservice

rxjava2 version 2.1.5

Trying to understand RxJava2 multiple subscriptions of an observable.
Have a simple file watch service that tracks create,modify,delete of files in a directory.
I add 2 subscribers and expect events to be printed on both subscribers. 
When I copy a file into the watched directory, I see one subscriber print out the event. Then, when I delete the file I see the second subscriber print out the event.
I was expecting events to be printed by both subscribers. What am I missing here?

```java
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystem;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import io.reactivex.BackpressureStrategy;
import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class MyRxJava2DirWatcher {

    public Flowable<WatchEvent<?>> createFlowable(WatchService watcher, Path path) {

        return Flowable.create(subscriber -> {

            boolean error = false;
            WatchKey key;
            try {

                key = path.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                subscriber.onError(e);
                error = true;
            }

            while (!error) {
                key = watcher.take();

                for (final WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                    subscriber.onNext(event);
                }

                key.reset();
            }

        }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Path path = Paths.get("c:\\temp\\delete");
        final FileSystem fileSystem = path.getFileSystem();
        WatchService watcher = fileSystem.newWatchService();

        MyRxJava2DirWatcher my = new MyRxJava2DirWatcher();
        my.createFlowable(watcher, path).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()).subscribe(event -> {
            System.out.println("1>>Event kind:" + event.kind() + ". File affected: " + event.context() + ". "
                    + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        }, onError -> {
            System.out.println("1>>" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            onError.printStackTrace();
        });

        // MyRxJava2DirWatcher my2 = new MyRxJava2DirWatcher();

        my.createFlowable(watcher, path).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()).subscribe(event -> {
            System.out.println("2>>Event kind:" + event.kind() + ". File affected: " + event.context() + ". "
                    + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        }, onError -> {
            System.out.println("2>>" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            onError.printStackTrace();
        });

        TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1000);

    }
}
```

---

The output looks like the following

```
2>>Event kind:ENTRY_CREATE. File affected: 1.txt. RxCachedThreadScheduler-2
2>>Event kind:ENTRY_MODIFY. File affected: 1.txt. RxCachedThreadScheduler-2
1>>Event kind:ENTRY_DELETE. File affected: 1.txt. RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
```

Comment: Does your WatchService#register method provides the ability to register multiple listener or will the listener overwritten each time #register is invoked? If so, than it is clear, that the second subscription overwrites the first #register listener and the first subscription does not get notified anymore. Just multicast the observable: http://blog.danlew.net/2016/06/13/multicasting-in-rxjava/

Comment: @hans
When I add say 20 files, I get 40 notifications, 20 for each subscriber thats 10 create +10 modify events per subscriber. So its not as if the first subscriber is over written. 
I also tried creating anew instance of the flowable, but nothing changed.
I will look into the multicasting as thats what I really want, but I also need to understand the current behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens is that you share the same `WatchService` between two `Flowable`s and they race for events in it. If you pass in the `FileSystem` instead and call `newWatchService()` in `Flowable.create`, you should receive all events as many times as there are `Subscriber`s:

```java
public Flowable<WatchEvent<?>> createFlowable(FileSystem fs, Path path) {

    return Flowable.create(subscriber -> {

        WatchService watcher = fs.newWatchService();

        subscriber.setCancellable(() -> watcher.close());

        boolean error = false;
        WatchKey key;
        try {

            key = path.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            subscriber.onError(e);
            error = true;
        }

        while (!error) {
            key = watcher.take();

            for (final WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                subscriber.onNext(event);
            }

            key.reset();
        }

    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);

}
```

Note also that you should use `subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation(), false)` to avoid deadlocking the `poll` with your `Subscriber`.

Comment: Works as expected now. Thank you.

Comment: I did not understand the javadoc or the false flag that is recommended.

If there is a {@link #create(FlowableOnSubscribe, BackpressureStrategy)} type source up in the
     * chain, it is recommended to have {@code requestOn} false to avoid same-pool deadlock
     * because requests may pile up behind an eager/blocking emitter

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/4770) is the discussion about it.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two different Flowables for two different subscribers. Have it be one Flowable being subscribed to twice like the following.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Path path = Paths.get("c:\\temp\\delete");
        final FileSystem fileSystem = path.getFileSystem();
        WatchService watcher = fileSystem.newWatchService();

        MyRxJava2DirWatcher my = new MyRxJava2DirWatcher();
        Flowable myFlowable = my.createFlowable(watcher, path);

        myFlowable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()).subscribe(event -> {
            System.out.println("1>>Event kind:" + event.kind() + ". File affected: " + event.context() + ". "
                    + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        }, onError -> {
            System.out.println("1>>" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            onError.printStackTrace();
        });

        myFlowable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()).subscribe(event -> {
            System.out.println("2>>Event kind:" + event.kind() + ". File affected: " + event.context() + ". "
                    + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        }, onError -> {
            System.out.println("2>>" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            onError.printStackTrace();
        });

        TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1000);

    }
}
```

Comment: This doesnt change anything for me. The results are identical to the code I had.

Just a snippet of the output....
I dont get create and modify events for each file in  threadpool 1 and thread pool2

1>>Event kind:ENTRY_CREATE. File affected: 1.txt. RxComputationThreadPool-1
1>>Event kind:ENTRY_MODIFY. File affected: 1.txt. RxComputationThreadPool-1
2>>Event kind:ENTRY_CREATE. File affected: 2 - Copy (10).txt. RxComputationThreadPool-2
1>>Event kind:ENTRY_MODIFY. File affected: 2 - Copy (10).txt. RxComputationThreadPool-1

Comment: I'll delete my answer in a bit, since @akarnokd is king regarding Rx